# can you get metadata of a PHP method with reflection classes?

Tags: php, methods, reflection, metadata

I'd like to retreive custom meta data at runtime from a PHP method like this:

```
/** description of function
 * @myCustomMetaData value
*/
function x($a,$b) { ... }
```

But it seems the PHP Reflection classes do not support this and I can't find any related questions about it. Is it simply not possible?

Answer (score -1):

found it already.

```
    $methodReflection = new ReflectionMethod('\path\to\my\Class', 'methodName');
    print_r($methodReflection->getDocComment());
```